# Implementing Stream Integer for Coefficients

Tags: haskell

As part of a [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf) (from 2013) for which I'm self-learning, consider the following background:

> The essential idea is to work with generating functions of the form
>
> a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + · · · + an*x^n + . . .
>
> where x is just a “formal parameter” (that is, we will never actually substitute any values for
>   x; we just use it as a placeholder) and all the coefficients ai are
>   integers. We will store the coefficients a0, a1, a2, . . . in a Stream
>   Integer.

I attempted to implement `x :: Stream Integer`

> by noting that x = 0 + 1x + 0x^2 + 0x^3 + . . . .

```
x :: Stream Integer
x = Cons 0 (Cons 1 $ streamRepeat 0)
```

for the following definitions:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat x = Cons x (streamRepeat x)
```

Is my `x` implementation correct? I'm not sure if, given the above background, I'm properly capturing the coefficients of a0, a1, ..., an.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. You could slightly improve `streamRepeat` definition by adding sharing, but this shouldn't matter for the homework's purposes.

Comment: Could you please say more about sharing?

Comment: @KevinMeredith You could use `Data.Function.fix`: `streamRepeat x = fix (Cons x)`.  This takes care of the "tying the knot" for you.  Alternatively, you could do `streamRepeat x = let x' = Cons x x' in x'`, which means that the tail of your stream is referring back to the same spot in memory as the head of your stream, which then refers back to the same spot in memory for its tail as the original tail.

Comment: @KevinMeredith [I drew a picture](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/357c0ac7a0f9f54776d1) to try to help explain what this is doing.  Basically, when you've defined `streamRepeat` like this, you tell it that certain values aren't just equal, they're literally the same thing.  This allows the compiler to share those values and make a fair number of optimizations.