# Multiplying Streams (representing polynomial coefficients)

Tags: haskell

For this 2013 [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf), I'm trying to multiply 2 Streams.

```
xStream :: Stream Integer
xStream = Cons 0 (Cons 1 $ streamRepeat 0)

instance Num (Stream Integer) where
    fromInteger x = Cons x $ streamRepeat 0
    negate        = streamMap (* (-1)) 
    (+) xs ys     = combineStreams (+) xs ys
    (*) xs ys     = multStreams xs ys
    abs           = streamMap abs
```

Here's the professor's help for how to implement multiplication of the above Stream:

```
 Multiplication is a bit trickier. Suppose A = a0 + xA` and B = b0 +
 xB0 are two generating functions we wish to multiply. We reason as
 follows: AB = (a0 + xA`)B   
             = a0B + xA`B    
             = a0(b0 + xB0) + xA`B   
             = a0b0 + x(a0B0 + A`B)
```

Here's my attempt:

```
multStreams :: Stream Integer -> Stream Integer -> Stream Integer
multStreams (Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) = addXY + rest
  where addXY = Cons (x + y) $ streamRepeat 0 
        rest  = (xStream *) $ (streamMap (*x) ys + (xs * b))
```

with the following definitions:

```
data Stream a = Cons a (Stream a)

streamRepeat :: a -> Stream a
streamRepeat x = Cons x (streamRepeat x)    

streamMap :: (a -> b) -> Stream a -> Stream b
streamMap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) rest
   where rest = streamMap f xs

combineStreams :: (a -> b -> c) -> Stream a -> Stream b -> Stream c
combineStreams f (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) = Cons (f x y) rest
   where rest = combineStreams f xs ys
```

Note that `xStream` is the same as `x` per this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559110/implementing-stream-integer-for-coefficients).

When I tried the above implementation, my call to `multStreams` does not terminate.

Please help me understand what's wrong with my above `multStream` function - both in implementation and whether I even implemented the professor's explanation of multiplication  correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that your definition of `multStreams` directly uses `(*)` on `Stream` in the definition of `rest`, which isn't what was intended by the given reasoning.

If you consider the equation `AB = a0b0 + x(a0B0 + A'B)`, it tells you what the first term of `AB` should be precisely: `a0b0` is a constant, i.e. part of the first term, and every other term in the stream is multiplied by `x`, i.e. not part of the first term.

It also tells you that the *remaining* terms of the `AB` come from `a0B0 + A'B` - because shifting it along by one with a `Cons` is equivalent to multipltying by `x`.

The key difference with what you've done is that the first element of the output stream can be constructed without any recursive calls to `(*)`, even though the remaining elements use one.

So something like this should work:

```
multStreams :: Stream Integer -> Stream Integer -> Stream Integer
multStreams (Cons x xs) b@(Cons y ys) =
    Cons (x * y) (streamMap (*x) ys + multStreams xs b)
```